# WebService on IIS with IIS-Manager

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I just created a simple test WebService with Asp.net called

```
MyWebService.asmx
```

I can't access it from exteriour, cause Visual Studio don't allow this..
So I wanted to make a own IIS Webserver to host my Webservice, but
how do I add my "MyWebService.asmx" to the IIS with the IIS-Manager?

Hope someone can help me.. Google didnt help me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to publish this WebService (right click on the project -> Publish) and host it using IIS like a regular Web Application.

Comment: I did publish it, but I can't open it, so the browser always tell, that Page is not valid..

Answer (score 0):

1. Just create a new application, as you would do if you create a "real" ASP application
2. put, for completeness and to be sure the app is running a default.aspx into the root dir, which says something like "app is running!"
3. put the ASMX file into the directory (i think it will be place in the APP_CODE directory, but i'm not sure 100%)
4. config your webservice in the global.asax, without it nothing will happen (hint: also configure the help page for webservices, otherwise users accessing it will get the interface description in the browser)

A longer description of that can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70%28v=vs.80%29.aspx